# Spring boot http encoding is not working?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, utf-8

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FNMf.png)I have a spring boot api  which is https enabled but when i invoke http from rest client it is giving me the response in "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" format instead of UTF-8

How to override this default behavior?

I have tried with below properties but none of them seems to a solution
application.yml:

```
spring:
  http.encoding.charset : UTF-8
  http.encoding.enabled: true
  http.encoding.force:  true
  http.encoding.force-request: true
  http.encoding.force-response: true

server:
  port: 9190
  http.port: 9098
  http.ssl.both.enabled: true
  https.redirect.port: 9443
  ssl.enabled: true
  compression.mime-types:  application/json
  uri-encoding : UTF-8
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeResource {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;

      @PostMapping(value = "store/employee", consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        public String storeEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeBO employeeBO) {

          empRepo.save(employeeBO);
          return "Data saved sucessfully";
        }

}
```

Comment: how does your rest endpoint look like?

Comment: http://localhost:9190/store/employee  - <http>://<host>:<port>/store/employee

Comment: Since above endpoint is  SSL enabled am getting "Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS." which is expected but the charset remains ISO even after adding all the mentioned properties in yml

Comment: No I meant the implementation

Comment: Both produce and consume methods using  
 application/json;charset=UTF-8 media type

Comment: did i answer your question?

Comment: No show the Java code of the RestController please

Comment: Pls find it in the body section

Comment: How do you know that the response is sent as ISO-8859-1? Do you see that in a header somewhere? Because for that given string the byte-stream of both encodings is exactly the same (that's true for all strings containing only ASCII characters).

Comment: service is ssl and https enabled if i invoke my endpoint with http it is returning 400"Bad request" and in response header i can see content type text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1.Please check the screen shot added. I just want the response header encoding in UTF-8 if somebody access my endpoint with http

Comment: When http is not allowed, default message uses ISO encoding. Should be UTF-8

Comment: This is the default charset part of HTTP specification, can you check with TLS to make sure it returns desired charset

Comment: @NirajJha : any suggestions to override TLS charset?